# Displaying post content based on id variable - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

firstly **thanks** if you've taken the time to try and help out here!

I've recently bought this plugin:
[Pro Panel Wordpress Themes Options Panel](http://codecanyon.net/item/propanel-wordpress-theme-options-panel/866565)

It's a brilliant item, however one of the functions is to 'select page from a drop down menu'. I for some reason can only echo the page slug: `what-we-do`

I want to echo `the_title` and `the_content`.

```
<?php     
    $blockwho = get_option('good_blockwho');
    echo $blockwho;
?>
```

The above code outputs the slug (its the code given to me in the documentation).

And the below code is what's in my functions

```
$options[] = array( "name" => __('Who We Are Block','framework_localize'),
    "desc" => __('My Description.','framework_localize'),
    "id" => $shortname."_blockwho",
    "std" => "1",
    "type" => "select",
    "options" => $tt_pages);
```

Apologies if this is a newbie question, and **thanks again** for taking the time to read/help!

Answer (score 1):

Ok so with a little help from a friend i've got the code working at long last! For any one who contacted me and tried to help be it in other questions or here, thank you!

```
<?php
$blockwho = get_option('good_blockwho');
$homeblockwho = get_pages ('post_name='.$blockwho);

foreach ($homeblockwho as $hbw) {   
  $content = $hbw->post_content;
  $content=do_shortcode($content);
  if ($content!='') echo "<h2><span>".$hbw->post_title."</h2></span>";
  apply_filters('the_content', $content);

  echo "".$content."";
}
?>
```

Comment: Tag yourself as the answer, for future visitors. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys after a couple days of testing, reading up on the Wordpress Codex i've finally been able to achieve half of what i wanted. The following code posts the content, with shortcode enabled.

```
 <?php
  $blockwho = get_option('good_blockwho');
  $homeblockwho = get_pages ('post_name='.$blockwho); ?>


<?php foreach ($homeblockwho as $hbw) {        
    $content = $hbw->post_content;
    apply_filters('the_content', $content);

    echo "".do_shortcode($content)."";
}?>
```

Hope this code is useful, ill post an update when i am able to also post the page title.